# Squared dft Coefficient defines?

Tags: dft

What does the squared magnitude of the DFT coeffiecient tell me,
where do I use it? 
what does it define?

$|X(k)^2| = ???$

I am curious to  know  because the Amplitude is given by the formula $A_k = \sqrt{|X(k)|}$

So it cannot be the amplitude.

It would help me alot if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum (or integral) of the magnitude squared of a signal gives the signal *energy*. [Parseval's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) tells us that the sum (or integral) of a function's magnitude squared is equal to the sum (or integral) of its Fourier transform's magnitude squared. In the case of the DFT the relation is:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} | x[n] |^2  =   \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} | X[k] |^2
$$
 Therefore, if you square the magnitude of all the bins of the DFT and add them up, it is another way to find the signal's energy (Multiplied by the number of elements in the signal). So the magnitude squared of any individual bin gives you a value proportional to the signal energy *at that particular frequency*.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your earlier comment. As far as misinterpreting the OP's question, I assumed that $|X(k)^2|$ was a typo and that he really meant $|X(k)|^2$. Since you are convinced this is not the case, I invite you to submit your own answer.

Comment: No it wasn't a typo https://www.dropbox.com/s/zms7i2pk8ajdrl7/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202013-12-19%20kl.%2023.58.12.png

Comment: Um... the picture you linked to shows that it IS in fact a typo. In your question you typed it as $|X(k)^2|$, and in the image you linked to it is listed as $|X(k)|^2$. So in short, my original assumption (and answer, if I may be so bold) was correct.

Comment: Oh my good.. I am becomming blind..

Thank you for your very very helpful response :)
So taking the value gives me the energy of the signal..
Usually the amplitude for DFT coefficient is given by the formula $\frac{1}{N} · \sqrt{|X(k)|}$

But by using goertzel, the amplitude is given by  $\frac{2}{N} · \sqrt{|X(k)|^2}$ times 2 because it is single sided, but  I cannot understand how come the formula looks like that??

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with your premise. This is what I have from [Proakis and Manolakis](http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Signal-Processing-4th-Edition/dp/0131873741): 

Values of the DFT: $X(k) = \sum^{N-1}_{n=0} x(n)e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$

Fourier coefficients of Discrete time periodic signals: $c_k = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} x(n)e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$

So $X(k) = Nc_k$. Where are you getting your equation for DFT coefficients?

Comment: I agree on that that DFT coefficient er given by the formula $X(k)=∑N−1n=0x(n)e^{−j2πkn/N}$ and the amplitude spektrum for the given k is given by the formula $\frac{1}[N} \sqrt{|X(k)|}$...

but by Using the modified  goertzel algorithmh
ttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm
you compute $|X(k)|^2$, and derive the amplitude specktrum using  $\frac{1}[N} \sqrt{|X(k)|^2}$ => double sided amplitude spectrum. 

So how come is the amplitude spectrum by using goertzel given by taking the squared DFT, and not just Abs?

Comment: I think what is happening here is that you are confusing amplitude spectrum with power spectrum. Have a look at slides 18-19 in [this presentation](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/ghulam/Documents/CEN352/DSP_CEN352_ch4_DFT.pdf). Also notice that there is no square root of $|X(k)|$ for amplitude *or* power spectrum. Can you cite a source for your claim that $A_k = \sqrt{|X(k)|}$ ?

Comment: I  think you just solved my problem.. 
I just rechecked it, and it says that $A_k = \frac{1}{N} |X(k)|$ which is the same as $\frac{1}{N} \sqrt{|x(k)|^2}$

Comment: Great! Feel free to edit the typos out of your original question and mark the answer as correct.